# What is the difference between "se chercher" and "chercher"?

Tags: verbes-pronominaux

Is there a difference between the following two sentences?

> a) Elle cherche un emploi.
> b) Elle se cherche un emploi.

(I saw sentence B in a youtube video, and I generated sentence A using deepL translator)

---

I know from the answer to [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17547/is-there-a-good-explanation-of-different-types-of-pronominal-verbs), "se" can sometimes be added for emphasis:

> In ["Je m'aggripe à Tom"], the subject (me) attach the primary object (me) to secondary
> objet (Tom). I could have juste said "J'agrippe Tom", but by using a
> pronoun I created an emphasis on myself, indicated that I really
> latched on him.

That is, it seems like "J'agrippe Tom" and "Je m'aggripe à Tom" have similar meanings. Am I allowed to do this with any verb that takes a direct object? for example: Je mange une pomme --> Je me mange à une pomme?

---

edit: a user suggested that [Concerning Reflexive Pronouns](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21432/concerning-reflexive-pronouns) might answer my question. i could benefit from someone making it more clear how that information answers my questions above.

the linked question gives many examples of pronomial verbs (classifying different types of pronomial verbs, and the ways that the subject is (by degrees) "acted upon" by someone else or by themselves), but it doesn't give examples of verbs that can sometimes take a "se" and sometimes not. i don't understand what difference (if there is any) between "se chercher" and "chercer".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concerning Reflexive Pronouns](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21432/concerning-reflexive-pronouns)

Comment: @jlliagre: i looked through the accepted answer to the question you linked to, but i don't know how to use that information to understand the difference between *se chercher* and *chercher*, nor if i'm able to add a "se" for emphasis. it still was a useful link for me to read, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Je **me** mange une pomme* is a case of "autobenefactive" form. It is considered informal outside regions where it is very common (Southern France).

*Je **me** cherche du travail/un emploi* is more usual because while you can't eat an apple for someone else, it is still possible to look for a job for someone else (e.g. *Je cherche du travail pour mon fils*.)

However, if you just say *elle cherche un emploi* without more precision, everyone will assume she is doing it for herself so *elle **se** cherche un emploi* can be considered slightly redundant but nevertheless common, especially in Canadian French. Regardless of the grammatical difference, there is no difference in meaning between ***je cherche** du travail* et ***je me cherche** du travail*.

***Agripper*** is transitive direct: *J'agrippe son bras*.

When used pronominally, the direct object is the reflexive pronoun ***me*** so ***son bras*** becomes a *complément d'objet second* and requires the preposition ***à***: *Je m'agrippe **à** son bras*, i.e. literally "*J'agrippe moi à son bras*".

On the other hand, while *manger* is also transitive direct, ***me*** is not the direct object because I do not eat myself here. It is still the apple that is eaten so the apple stays the direct object: *Je me mange une pomme*, i.e. "*Je mange une pomme (pour/à) moi*".

Comment: so, is it possible to add a "se" to any verb that can be done "for someone else" or "for the benefit of someone else"? would you be willing to add some more example sentences where an added "se" is allowed (or not allowed) ? (and indeed, i saw "elle se cherche un emploi" from a Québecois journalism youtube video about poverty)

Comment: i'm also a little bit confused about why it is "Je m'aggripe **à** Tom" instead of "Je m'aggripe Tom", since without the "se", it is "J'aggripe Tom". Does this addition of "à" happen with other verbs that can optionally take a "se" for emphasis?

Comment: your edit really helped clarify what was confusing me. thanks. the only thing i'm still uncertain about is if i can add a "se" to almost any verb that can be done "*pour/à*" someone, for emphasis. (eg are the following acceptable? "Je me chante un chanson" ((i sang a song [for my benefit / to myself])*, "Je me nettoye la cuisine" *(i cleaned the kitchen (for my benefit))*). is this use of adding "se" for emphasis, identical to just adding "pour moi" or "à moi" at the end (eg "Je cherche un emploi pour moi", "Je mange une pomme pour moi", "Je nettoye la cuisine pour moi") ?

Comment: *Je me chante une chanson* is absolutely fine. It is a case where the extra pronoun is fully legitimate. I'm both the performer and the listener, nothing colloquial or regional here. On the other hand, *je me nettoie la cuisine* is rare and regional because normally *je me nettoie* implies I clean some part or the whole of my body and a kitchen is unlikely to qualify... That said, I wouldn't rule out an intelligent house scheduling its own cleaning saying with its robotic voice *je me nettoie la cuisine* ;-)

Comment: Great answer. My two centimes, from a native speaker: « elle se cherche un emploi » informal but common in the south, I always felt the unspoken implication that she's not getting any help in her search (but maybe I'm overthinking it). When the educated southerner says « je me cherche un emploi »,  there's a bit of humour implied, not sure why, maybe because being a southern expression, where people are more laid back, you are implying there's no big urgency in the search.

Comment: I have never heard anyone say « J'aggripe Tom », sounds totally wrong to me, it's always been « Je m'aggripe à Tom » in my lifetime. Je me chante une chanson, totally normal. Je me nettoie la cuisine sounds fine to me too, implying that it's a big job you've been meaning to undertake, the « me » is there for emphasis imho. If you say, « je nettoie la cuisine » it's factual and non-emotional, but « je me nettoie la cuisine » means you're taking the job at heart. « Qu'est-ce que tu fais? - Je nettoie la cuisine » mais « Qu'est-ce que tu fais dimanche? - Je me nettoie la cuisine! » :-)

Comment: Dans certains cas on peut se demander si c'est le pronom qui fait la différence ou simplement le fait que l'employer en contexte évoque un modèle comme _se taper_ avec le substantif associé au verbe, comme le nettoyage. Dans d'autres cas, comme avec la pomme, je trouve la phrase en trompe l'oeil et j'attends un complément comme _au visage/sur la gueule_. C'est que l'emploi avec le pronom est plus usuel avec le sens de (se) _prendre_ dans mon coin à mon avis. Sinon je l'interprète comme mettant l'accent sur le fait que ça se déroule présentement, comme avec _je suis en train de_.

Comment: @PatrickT *J'agrippe Tom* alone is unlikely but *j'agrippe Tom par le bras* or *j'agrippe Tom par l'épaule* are common.

Comment: @jlliagre, very true.  P.S. I repeatedly misspelled agripper above...

Comment: @jilliagre - The "autobenefactive" form, as in "Je me mange une pomme" parallels the informal American English usage, "I'm going to eat me an apple", "I'm going to catch me a fish" etc, where "me" means "for myself".