# Why do we need to include the reflexive pronoun in past tense constructions like in Qu'est-ce qui s'est passé?

Tags: grammaire, passé-composé, pronoms-réfléchis

I find it rather weird that the reflexive pronouns `me, te, se` etc. are included the passé composé form of reflexive verbs.

Example:

1. Qu'est-ce qui *s*'est passé?
2. Je *me* suis lavé
3. Nous *nous* sommes habillés.

What I don't understand is how exactly the reflexive pronouns in the sentences above help to clarify the past because we wouldn't have used `être` if the receiver of the action were someone else, so I'm really confused how this works. It seems to me that `être` is taking these pronouns as indirect object pronouns.

Comment: Contrast the tenses of *nous sommes habillés* with *nous nous sommes habillés*.  Related questions but not exactly a duplicate: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21432/concerning-reflexive-pronouns https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17547/is-there-a-good-explanation-of-different-types-of-pronominal-verbs?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: The present also has the pronouns and so does the infinitive: se laver and s'habiller. Perhaps you need to review how reflexive verbs work in French, regardless of tense.

Answer (score 4):

These pronouns are not there to clarify the meaning but to set it. Removing them is possible but significantly affects it:

> *Qu'est-ce qui s'est passé ?* : What happened? (some event)

> *Qu'est-ce qui est passé ?* : What has moved/gone? (some object)

> *Je me suis lavé.* : I got washed (literally: "I washed myself").

> *Je suis lavé.* : I'm washed (I'm clean)

> *Nous nous sommes habillés.* : We got dressed (some time ago).

> *Nous sommes habillés.* : We are dressed (now) (we are not in underwear/naked).

Note that *je suis lavé* and *nous sommes habillés* are ambiguous, as lkl answer shows. I picked the most likely meaning where *lavé* and *habillés* are adjectives *attributs du sujet*. These sentences migth also be understood to be passive voice verbs:

> *Je suis lavé.* : I'm getting washed (by someone else)

> *Je suis habillé.* : I'm being dressed.

The real subject is often explicit in passive mode: *je suis lavé par l'infirmière*, *je suis habillé par un styliste*.

Comment: I now get the difference in meanings, but what I can't seem to get is how the reflexive pronoun changes the subject or makes it clearer who actually did the action from the way its used in the sentence. I see it like an indirect object pronoun

Comment: In the *se laver* and *s'habiller* reflexive verbs, the subject is also the object. That's the definition of [reflexive](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/french-easy-learning/reflexive-verbs). *Qu'est-ce **qui** s'est passé* (which is equivalent to *qu'est-ce **qu'il** s'est passé*) is slightly different because the subject is impersonal (***il** se passe quelque chose*) so both the subject and the object are meaningless...

Comment: If you say *je lave*, you mean that you are washing something (or perhaps someone but not yourself). If you add *me* in *je me lave*, then you are still the person acting but you are also the object, i.e. what is washed.

Answer (score 1):

As Jlliagre explained, the meaning does change without the reflexive pronoun - and the grammatical construction often does too.

*Qu'est-ce qui s'est passé / Je me suis lavé / Nous nous sommes habillés* = *passé composé* of pronominal verbs

*Qu'est-ce qui est passé* is still the *passé composé*, albeit of the non-pronominal verb *passer*

However, *Je suis lavé / Nous sommes habillés* is a different grammatical construction altogether - it's the passive voice in the present tense.

Comment: In those last cases, how is it necessarily passive without a complément d'agent?  Without more context (par quelqu'un, de quelque chose, en...), the present tense holds, and the past participle functions as an adjective.

Comment: @livresque Yes, that's precisely what I just added in my answer.